# HttpUtility.UrlEncode not encoding single quotes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to encode a query string using the `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` method

The string is:

```
www.example.come?a=1&b='mia'&c=33
```

the output is:

```
www.example.come%3fa%3d1%26b%3d'mia'%26c%3d33
```

Why did the quotation marks not get encoded and is there a way for me to ensure that they do?

Comment: Maybe because `'` is a valid URL character (?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid

Comment: Weird, _HttpUtility.UrlEncode("www.example.come?a=1&b='mia'&c=33)_ returns _www.example.come%3fa%3d1%26b%3d%27mia%27%26c%3d33_ here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These characters are valid for URL  according to [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2)    `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=`